# How to Create a Web Service Client with JSF?

Tags: web-services, jsf, netbeans, webservice-client

I have easily created a **JSF** project with **NetBeans** that delivers a **web service**, as explained in [this video tutorial](http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/javaee5/screencasts/hello-simple-client-glassfish/).

I have *another* **JSF** project (in which I do *not* use JSP pages), which consume the above web service (**web service client**). Using netbeans, as shown in [the above tutorial](http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/javaee5/screencasts/hello-simple-client-glassfish/), I can easily configure a JSP page to use the web service, but I could not found **any tutorial which describe how JSF can use a web service?**

I will be grateful to you if one can give a link to a tutorial or example or any hint that show how JSF can use a web service.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put exactly that Java code which they have shown in the *scriptlets* of a JSP in the (post)constructor or an action method of a JSF managed bean.